# SQL30082N Attempt to establish connection failed with security reason 5

Tags: db2, oledbconnection

I'm getting this error when i try to connect to DB2 Database server using OLEDBConnection in Visual studio 2008 windows application developed in c#:

```
SQL30082N Attempt to establish connection failed with security reason 5
```

I'm using Microsoft OLEDB Provider for DB2. When i try to connect i am getting the above error.

I am using the below connection string for connecting to DB2

```
ConnectionStr = "Provider=IBMDADB2;Database="SampDB";Hostname=114.968.25.61;Protocol=TCPIP;Port=60001;Uid =testuser; Pwd=!DB2User!;";
```

I am 100% sure that this userid is correct. My DB2 client provider version is 8.0

In my desktop i am getting this error. but this windows application works well on all others machine. Please help me in fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Info Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql30082n.html), reason code `5` for SQLSTATE `SQL30082N` means that the UserId is missing.

I think what may be the issue (if you copied and pasted your exact connection string) is that there is an extra space after `Uid`.

If you're using .NET, then you may want to look at the [`OleDbConnectionString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) class. It will format and escape the connection string as needed.